# .htaccess redirection for url pattern

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to add code line in `.htaccess` to redirect a package of url with the same pattern :

```
shop.my-example.com/blog/{my-cat}/{number}
```

To a new site :

```
https://my-new-site.com/blog/{my-cat}/{number}
```

For the moment I'm using this code line :

```
Redirect permanent /blog/ https://www.my-new-site.com/blog/
```

But it works only fr the url `shop.my-example.com/blog/`

Answer (score 0):

Using `RedirectMatch`, You may use this rule as your top rule (**before all other rules**):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/blog/.+)$ https://www.my-new-site.com/$1
```

Make sure to test in a new browser or clear your browser cache before testing this change.